# While executing the stored procedure from backend(MSSQL 2012).Unable to open a few modules from pb12.5 desktop application

Tags: sql-server

We have an stored procedure to transfer the data(contract data) from database 1 to database 2(interfacing with SAP to Intermeidate Database , then our database), and this contain loops and more that one table in the execution.And we have an PB12.5 desktop application with several modules like procurement,crewing, employee etc.The issue is here while executing the stored procedure from MSSQL using exec, it will take nearly 2 minutes depend on the recieved data from SAP.During the execution I'm unable to open procurement window and it is opening once the stored procedure completed the execution.The other side employee window is opening without any issue.The below are my findings/comments

1. Procurement module is using table1 and table2 , but in the stored procedure we are not using any of this tables.We are using table 3 and table 4(but later we will use the table from procurement module in proc)
   2.While executing the proc Im able to select the tables from procurement module using select * from table1.
   3.None of the table is locking from proc.
   4.We have tried the same scenarios from different PC same issue exist.
   5.Later we will extend the stored procedure with more tables and multiple loops(cursor)

Below are the small part of procedure(we have to extend more and it is hold now because of this issue)

Many thanks in advance.

```
alter PROC [spectwosuite].[CST_GENERATE_IPurchase_contract] 
as begin

SET NOCOUNT ON;
/**/

--truncate table spectwosuite.CUSTOM_SAP_CONTRACT_ITEM;
--truncate table spectwosuite.CUSTOM_SAP_CONTRACT_header;
--truncate table spectwosuite.CUSTOM_SAP_PROC_LOG;

--Variable declaration
DECLARE @MATERIALNO VARCHAR(20);
DECLARE @PURCHASEDOCNO VARCHAR(20);
DECLARE @PORTID NUMERIC(15);
DECLARE @PRICE DECIMAL(11,2);
DECLARE @PKID NUMERIC(16);

DECLARE @STOCKTYPEID NUMERIC(15);
DECLARE @STOCKTYPECODE VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE @STNAME VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE @UNITID NUMERIC(15);
DECLARE @BUSFLOWID NUMERIC(15);
DECLARE @BUSSTATUSID NUMERIC(15);

DECLARE @ITEMNO VARCHAR(5);
DECLARE @SUBITEMNO VARCHAR(10);
DECLARE @STOCKDISID NUMERIC(15);

DECLARE @PURCONTRACTID NUMERIC(15);
DECLARE @REVISIONNO NUMERIC(15);
DECLARE @DESCR NVARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @ADDRESSID NUMERIC(15);
DECLARE @DELTERMSID NUMERIC(15);
DECLARE @PAYTERMSID NUMERIC(15);
DECLARE @VALIDSTART DATETIME;
DECLARE @VALIDEND DATETIME;
DECLARE @CURRENCY NCHAR(3);
DECLARE @PRODUCTGROUPID NUMERIC(15);
DECLARE @PURCONTRACTPRODUCTGROUPID NUMERIC(15);
DECLARE @MATERIALGRP NVARCHAR(20);
DECLARE @NETPRICE NUMERIC(16,6);
DECLARE @BASEPRICE NUMERIC(16,6);
DECLARE @PRODUCTGROUPLINEID NUMERIC(15);
DECLARE @SECTION VARCHAR(20);
DECLARE @PUREXIST NUMERIC(1);
DECLARE @HEADERPKID NUMERIC(16);

DECLARE @ITEMPRICE NUMERIC(16,6);
DECLARE @BASEITEMPRICE NUMERIC(16,2);
DECLARE @PURCONTRACTVARIABLEID NUMERIC(15);
DECLARE @FACTORVALUE NUMERIC(9,4);
DECLARE @ITEMPERCENTAGE NUMERIC(15,2);
DECLARE @ITEMPRICEDIFF1 NUMERIC(15,2);
DECLARE @ITEMPRICEDIFF2 NUMERIC(15,2);
DECLARE @ITEMPKID NUMERIC(16);

/*CONT1: Transfering all the portid and purchase document number to different table */


--PRINT 'CONT1 START'
--PRINT GETDATE();

BEGIN TRY
--BEGIN TRANSACTION

--BEGIN
    SET @SECTION='CONT1';
        BEGIN TRANSACTION CONT1
            INSERT INTO SAP_INTERFACE.spectwosuite.CUSTOM_SAP_CONTRACT_PORT
                       (PORTID
                       ,PURCHASE_DOC_NO
                        )
     
                SELECT DISTINCT PORTID,PURCHASE_DOC_NO FROM SAP_INTERFACE.spectwosuite.CUSTOM_SAP_CONTRACT_ITEM WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE IMPORT_STATUS IS NULL and DELETION_IND  NOT IN('L','1')  
                and portid>0 and MATERIAL_NO<>''  and  FACTOR>0 and
                       not exists (select PORTID from SAP_INTERFACE.spectwosuite.CUSTOM_SAP_CONTRACT_PORT where PORTID=SAP_INTERFACE.spectwosuite.CUSTOM_SAP_CONTRACT_PORT.PORTID 
                       and PURCHASE_DOC_NO =SAP_INTERFACE.spectwosuite.CUSTOM_SAP_CONTRACT_PORT.PURCHASE_DOC_NO) ORDER BY PURCHASE_DOC_NO,PORTID ASC;
            
        COMMIT TRANSACTION CONT1
--END

----INSERT INTO spectwosuite.CUSTOM_SAP_PROC_LOG
----           (STATUS
----           ,DESCRIPTION
----           ,PROCESSEDDATE
----           ,RECORDCOUNT)
----     VALUES
----           (1,
----           'CONT1'
----           ,GETDATE()
----           ,@@ROWCOUNT
----           );

--PRINT 'CONT1 END'
--PRINT GETDATE();
/* CONT1 END */

/*CONT2 Inserting new item which one dont have price in all ports*/

/*Variable declaration*/

--PRINT 'CONT2 START'
--PRINT GETDATE();

    --  BEGIN 
                SET @SECTION='CONT2';
                
                --SELECT DISTINCT CAST(MATERIAL_NO AS VARCHAR(20))AS MATERIAL_NO,PURCHASE_DOC_NO FROM SAP_INTERFACE.spectwosuite.CUSTOM_SAP_CONTRACT_ITEM WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE  PURCHASE_DOC_NO='4600000820' and IMPORT_STATUS IS NULL  and MATERIAL_NO<>'' and DELETION_IND NOT IN('L','1') and len(material_no)>0 and factor>0 and portid>0 ORDER BY MATERIAL_NO,PURCHASE_DOC_NO ASC;
                DECLARE CONT2CR CURSOR FOR
                SELECT DISTINCT CAST(MATERIAL_NO AS VARCHAR(20))AS MATERIAL_NO,PURCHASE_DOC_NO FROM SAP_INTERFACE.spectwosuite.CUSTOM_SAP_CONTRACT_ITEM WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE IMPORT_STATUS IS NULL  and MATERIAL_NO<>'' and DELETION_IND NOT IN('L','1') and len(material_no)>0 and factor>0 and portid>0 ORDER BY MATERIAL_NO,PURCHASE_DOC_NO ASC;
                OPEN CONT2CR
                FETCH NEXT FROM CONT2CR INTO @MATERIALNO,@PURCHASEDOCNO

                WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
                    BEGIN                               
                            BEGIN TRAN CONT2        
                                        select @PKID=MIN(pk_id),@PRICE=MIN(NET_PRICE) from SAP_INTERFACE.spectwosuite.CUSTOM_SAP_CONTRACT_ITEM WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE MATERIAL_NO=@MATERIALNO AND PURCHASE_DOC_NO=@PURCHASEDOCNO and  IMPORT_STATUS IS NULL and DELETION_IND NOT IN('L','1') and factor>0 and portid>0;
                                    /*Retreiving port details table*/
                                        DECLARE CONT2PORTCR CURSOR FOR
                                        SELECT DISTINCT portid FROM SAP_INTERFACE.spectwosuite.custom_sap_contract_port WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE (SAP_INTERFACE.spectwosuite.custom_sap_contract_port.purchase_doc_no = @PURCHASEDOCNO) and ( custom_sap_contract_port.portid > 0 )  ;
                                        OPEN CONT2PORTCR
                                        FETCH NEXT FROM CONT2PORTCR INTO @PORTID
                                        WHILE @PORTID>0
                                        BEGIN
                            

                                            IF @PORTID>0 
                                            BEGIN 
                                                BEGIN TRAN
                                                    /*Insert Script*/
                                                    SET @SECTION='ITEM_ADDITION';                               

                                                    IF (select COUNT(*) from SAP_INTERFACE.spectwosuite.CUSTOM_SAP_CONTRACT_ITEM WITH(NOLOCK) where  MATERIAL_NO=CAST(@MATERIALNO AS varchar(20)) AND PORTID=@PORTID and PURCHASE_DOC_NO=@PURCHASEDOCNO and IMPORT_STATUS IS NULL and DELETION_IND NOT IN('L','1') and factor>0 and portid>0)<=0
                                                    BEGIN                                           
                                                        INSERT INTO SAP_INTERFACE.spectwosuite.CUSTOM_SAP_CONTRACT_ITEM
                                                                                                    (DELETION_IND,PURCHASE_DOC_NO,ITEM_NO,MATERIAL_NO,SHORT_TEXT,MATERIAL_GRP,QTY,UOM,NET_PRICE,PORTID,TEMPPORTID,FACTOR)
                                                        select DELETION_IND,PURCHASE_DOC_NO,ITEM_NO,MATERIAL_NO,SHORT_TEXT,MATERIAL_GRP,QTY,UOM,NET_PRICE,@PORTID,1252,FACTOR  from SAP_INTERFACE.spectwosuite.CUSTOM_SAP_CONTRACT_ITEM WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE pk_id=@PKID and DELETION_IND<>'1'  and IMPORT_STATUS IS NULL;
                                                    END

                                                    SET @PORTID=0;
                                                COMMIT TRAN
                                            END
                                            FETCH NEXT FROM CONT2PORTCR INTO @PORTID
                                        END
                                        CLOSE CONT2PORTCR
                                        DEALLOCATE CONT2PORTCR
                            COMMIT TRAN CONT2
                        FETCH NEXT FROM CONT2CR INTO @MATERIALNO,@PURCHASEDOCNO
                    END

                    CLOSE CONT2CR
                    DEALLOCATE CONT2CR



--END 

--INSERT INTO spectwosuite.CUSTOM_SAP_PROC_LOG
--           (STATUS
--           ,DESCRIPTION
--           ,PROCESSEDDATE
--           ,RECORDCOUNT)
--     VALUES
--           (1,
--         'CONT2'
--         ,GETDATE()
--         ,@@ROWCOUNT
--         );

--PRINT 'CONT2 END'
--PRINT GETDATE();

/*CONT2 END*/

        /*CONT3*/

--PRINT 'CONT3 START'
--PRINT GETDATE();

SET @SECTION='CONT3';   
            BEGIN TRAN CONT3
                INSERT INTO spectwosuite.CUSTOM_SAP_CONTRACT_HEADER
                           (TABLEPKID
                           ,PURCHASE_DOC_NO
                           ,COMPANY_CODE
                           ,CREATED_ON_DATE
                           ,VENDOR_CODE
                           ,PAYMENT_TERMS
                           ,PURCHASE_GRP
                           ,VALIDITY_START
                           ,VALIDITY_END
                           ,YOUR_REFERENCE
                           ,OUR_REFERNCE
                           ,TARGET_AMOUNT
                           ,CURRENCY          
                           ,DESCRIPTION
                           ,SHIPCODE
                           ,STATUS           
                           ,CREATEDATE
                           ,VALIDATESTART
                           ,VALIDATEEND
                           ,INTERNAL_STATUS
                           ,INTERNAL_MESSAGE
                           )
                    SELECT 
                        PK_ID
                       ,PURCHASE_DOC_NO
                      ,COMPANY_CODE
                      ,CREATED_ON_DATE
                      ,VENDOR_CODE
                      ,PAYMENT_TERMS
                      ,PURCHASE_GRP
                      ,VALIDITY_START
                      ,VALIDITY_END
                      ,YOUR_REFERENCE
                      ,OUR_REFERNCE
                      ,TARGET_AMOUNT
                      ,CURRENCY
                      ,DESCRIPTION
                      ,SHIPCODE
                      ,STATUS
                      ,CREATEDATE
                      ,VALIDATESTART
                      ,VALIDATEEND
                      ,INTERNAL_STATUS
                      ,INTERNAL_MESSAGE
                  FROM SAP_INTERFACE.spectwosuite.CUSTOM_SAP_CONTRACT_HEADER WITH(NOLOCK)
                  where import_status is null and purchase_doc_no<>'' and validity_start<>'' and validity_end<>'' and currency<>''and status>0
                  and not exists(select pk_id from spectwosuite.CUSTOM_SAP_CONTRACT_HEADER WHERE TABLEPKID= SAP_INTERFACE.spectwosuite.CUSTOM_SAP_CONTRACT_HEADER.PK_ID)
            COMMIT TRAN CONT3
    --INSERT INTO spectwosuite.CUSTOM_SAP_PROC_LOG
 --          (STATUS
 --          ,DESCRIPTION
 --          ,PROCESSEDDATE
 --          ,RECORDCOUNT)
 --    VALUES
 --          (1,
    --     'CONT3'
    --     ,GETDATE()
    --     ,@@ROWCOUNT
    --     );
    
--PRINT 'CONT3 END'
--PRINT GETDATE();
        /*CONT3 END*/

        /*CONT4*/
        
--PRINT 'CONT4 START'
--PRINT GETDATE();
SET @SECTION='CONT4';   
            BEGIN TRAN CONT4
                    INSERT INTO spectwosuite.CUSTOM_SAP_CONTRACT_ITEM
                               (TABLEPKID,PURCHASE_DOC_NO
                               ,ITEM_NO
                               ,DELETION_IND
                               ,MATERIAL_NO
                               ,SHORT_TEXT
                               ,MATERIAL_GRP
                               ,QTY
                               ,UOM
                               ,NET_PRICE          
                               ,PORTID 
                               ,STOCKTYPEID
                               ,INTERNAL_MESSAGE
                               ,INTERNAL_STATUS 
                                ,CONTRACTTYPE
                                ,AGREEMENTSUBITEMNO 
                                ,FACTOR
                    )
        
            select  PK_ID,PURCHASE_DOC_NO
                  ,ITEM_NO
                  ,DELETION_IND
                  ,MATERIAL_NO
                  ,SHORT_TEXT
                  ,MATERIAL_GRP
                  ,QTY
                  ,UOM
                  ,NET_PRICE    
                  ,PORTID      
                  ,STOCKTYPEID
                  ,INTERNAL_MESSAGE
                  ,INTERNAL_STATUS
                    ,CONTRACTTYPE
                    ,AGREEMENTSUBITEMNO
                    ,FACTOR 
                      from SAP_INTERFACE.spectwosuite.CUSTOM_SAP_CONTRACT_ITEM WITH(NOLOCK)
                       where IMPORT_STATUS is null and MATERIAL_NO<>'' and DELETION_IND<>'L' AND PORTID>0 and FACTOR>0 and  LEN(SHORT_TEXT)>0 AND LEN(PURCHASE_DOC_NO)>0 AND 
                       not exists (select PK_ID from spectwosuite.CUSTOM_SAP_CONTRACT_ITEM where TABLEPKID= SAP_INTERFACE.spectwosuite.CUSTOM_SAP_CONTRACT_ITEM.PK_ID )  ORDER BY PK_ID ASC;
        COMMIT TRAN CONT4
        

--      /*Inserting History*/

--      /*Transfering process status to interface table.*/
    TRUNCATE TABLE spectwosuite.CUSTOM_SAP_CONTRACT_HEADER;
    TRUNCATE TABLE spectwosuite.CUSTOM_SAP_CONTRACT_ITEM;

    DELETE FROM spectwosuite.CUSTOM_SAP_PROC_LOG WHERE STATUS=99;
    COMMIT
--      /*PURCHASE CONTRACT CREATION END*/
--      SET NOCOUNT OFF;
--      --COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        DECLARE @ERRORNUMBER VARCHAR(20);
        DECLARE @ERRMSG VARCHAR(MAX);
        SET @ERRORNUMBER=CAST(ERROR_LINE() AS VARCHAR(20));
        SET @ERRMSG=ERROR_MESSAGE();

        BEGIN TRAN ER
            INSERT INTO spectwosuite.CUSTOM_SAP_PROC_LOG
                   (STATUS
                   ,DESCRIPTION
                   ,PROCESSEDDATE
                   ,RECORDCOUNT
                   ,ERRORMSG)
             VALUES
                   (
                   88,
                   @SECTION
                   ,getdate()
                   ,1
                   ,@ERRORNUMBER +','+ @ERRMSG
                   );
        COMMIT TRAN ER
    END CATCH
END
```

Try to add Begin tran and commit Tran without success

Comment: If you comment all transactions out, will something improve?

Comment: What you are experiencing is blocking. The reason it is taking so long is because you are using a cursor to do inserts. Looping is horribly slow and inefficient. In the code you posted I don't see any reason at all why you need loops. This could be done with a set based approach instead and the performance would improve a lot.

Comment: I have tried by removing transactions out no luck.

Comment: @Sean Lange. the above code is only a small part of the code. I have used a cursor in a few places in the remaining code. Let me convert this code to set based approach.Thanks